# Star Search algorithm in Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, path-finding

i want to build path finding in Google Maps with star search algorithm.  How can I use Star Search algorithm in Google Maps JavaScript API v3?

Comment: Do you have any code already? This looks like you want someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Google provides an API you can access as a starting point for your code:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Directions

Comment: how to custom with used "A* path finding or star search algorithm" ?

Comment: @user835971: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: I suppose he's talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm which is a path finding algorithm. But why would he not just use google's implementation instead for a route?